# How to make bootstrap 3 tab nav active by default?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using bootstrap 3 I am trying this exameple, using class="active" in the li element. Unfortunatelly when the page initially shows up neither tab pane is shown, the whole tab content is empty. The tab navs displayed correctly and when I explicitly click on a tab, the correct pane show up.

What I am missing?

Thanks in advance.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#graduation" data-toggle="tab">graduation</a></li>
    <li><a href="#graduate" data-toggle="tab">graduate</a></li>
    <li><a href="#extension" data-toggle="tab">extension</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="TabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="graduation">
        <p>
            anything
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="graduate">
        <p>
            graduate
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="extension">
        <p>
            extension
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You also need to specify the `active` class on the default `tab-pane` (and for fading tabs you need to add the `in` class), thus you should change

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="graduation">
```

to

**Bootstrap 3**

```
<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="graduation">
```

**Bootstrap 4**

```
<div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="graduation">
```

Comment: Thanks that was it. It is interesting how many not working sample are out there about this.

Comment: I always use the [official documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs), unless it is something I can't find there.

Comment: it works, although it doesnt set the tab itself to "selected" with aria-selected="true" should, but for me it doesnt work ATM

Comment: To highlight the tab itself use <a href="#graduation" class="active" data-toggle="tab"

Answer (score 18):

## Bootstrap 4

```
<div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="graduation">
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="graduation">
```

## Bootstrap 3

```
<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="graduation">
<div class="tab-pane fade in" id="graduation">
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone was here looking for a solution for react-bootstrap (like I was). There's a `defaultActiveKey` attribute you can specify on the Tab component. [Reference](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/tabs/#api)